# C increase int array address?

Tags: c, arrays, memory-address

So I have the following int array of 8 elements:

```
int v[8] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
```

and I pass this array to a function as argument in a loop

```
while(i < N) {
    .
    .
    function(v);
    .
    .
}
```

In this function I work with the first 4 elements and in the the next loop I want to increase the array address 4 positions so I can work with the last 4 elements. Since an int is 4 bytes, I was thinking in something like:

```
while(i < N) {
    .
    .
    function(v);
    .
    *v += 16;
}
```

However, this is not doing what I was expecting.

NOTE:
I can't use malloc since I am working on an embedded system. My array must be declared this way I believe.

QUESTION (edited):

How can I increase the address of my array so on second iteration v points to v[4]?

Comment: `Since an int is 4 bytes` - I understand you're working on an embedded system with platform-specific code and known word sizes, but still, don't hardcode anything that relies on that assumption. Always use `sizeof(int)` where you intend to relate a number to its byte width.

Comment: You can't.  `v` is an array which will always point to the start.  What I want to know is what exactly it is you're really trying to accomplish with this.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons it's just for a class assignment. My function is written in assembly. What I do in my function is to load the first 4 ints with the LDMIA instruction. So what I need is the address that points to the first element of the array, then the 5th element, and so on.
I could do the loop easily in my assembly function, however, I do it this way so later, after checking those 4 ints, I can decide what to do later in C code, outside the function.
The int array of 8 elements it's just used as dummy model.

Comment: If you need the address of an element of an array, you can use the address-of operator `&`.  So for the 5th element, you can do `&v[4]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, what you want to use is a pointer into your array.

If you do

```
int *p = v;
```

and then in your loop call

```
function(p);
```

and then do

```
p += 4;
```

and then during the next trip through your loop call

```
function(p);
```

again, it will do what you want.

Like any variable, once an array has had its address assigned, there's no way to move it around.  So there's no way to "increase the address of the array".  But by creating thie second, pointer variable, it's easy to move it around in the array.  (But if you like to think of it that way, yes, you are increasing the address held in the pointer.)

You don't have to worry about how big integers are (that is, you do *not* have to say something like `p += 4 * 4` or `p += 4 * sizeof(int)`), because pointer arithmetic in C is defined as always operating on the objects being pointed to.  (That is, the compiler automatically takes care of the multiplication by the size of the pointed-to object).

Comment: so classic that I find we could find many duplicate... One could write `int *v = (int []){0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};` in C99/C11

Comment: @Stargateur it seems like a bad idea to be able to modify the only pointer to an array if you ever need a reference to the beginning of it again, but yes that would work. (sorry you're right, it's not "statically allocated")

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh yes ofc if you need the begin of your array again my code is very bad ;). However, compound literal are not statically allocated. They are automatically allocated, so in theory if the compiler is not stupid, all should be OK.

Answer (score 3):

An **array is not a pointer**, so `v` is not a pointer -- it is an array, consisting of elements. You *can't* change the location in memory of *any* object in C.

When you just write `v`, it **evaluates** to a pointer to the first element. So, the solution is simple, assign it to an *actual* pointer you can modify:

```
int *p = v;
p += 3;
```

Comment: You could also _decay it to a pointer directly in the function argument by adding an offset to it_, e.g. `function(v + i * 3)` or `function(v + i)` depending on how `i` is incremented (not sure since it's not shown) **(fixed)**

Comment: That's not *modifying* though... but of course correct.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Any particular reason you and Felix have switch from adding 4 to adding 3?

Comment: @SteveSummit question asks `so on second iteration v points to v[3]?`

Comment: Thank you guys too. Much appreciated.